# How to write HTML *ngFor Angular style in GO html?

Tags: html, angular, go

My actual angular app will keep on a real server and will be submitted to browser without further "active" backend. All needed code is running in the browser and handle all input, calculation and outputs locally on browser.

Now my question: Is it possible to generate html code automatically as e,g, Angular does with html flowcontrol [*ngFor, *ngIf]. Is it possible to get a html/javascript by a web build form GO, which handle dynanics locally on browser only? Or must a backend running to handle a dynamic html actions?